# Nodejs/Javascript callback usage - Waiting for API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, jira

I've been searching and reading for a while now and just can't seem to grasp how I would achieve the following with only callbacks. I know this should be "simple" and do not wish to use promises or any other libraries to solve it as I want to understand how to only achieve this with callbacks.

I'm using Node.js to write a webform which if not provided a JIRA incident number, it will create the ticket, then send out an e-mail notification with the number.

What I have is... pseudo code:

```
function jiraCreate(req, res) {
    if req.body.inc is blank {
        var jiraInc = jiraAPI call to create ticket;
    } else {
        jiraInc = req.body.inc;
    }
    return jiraInc;
}

function jiraComment(req, res, jiraInc) {
    jiraCommentAPI(jiraInc) // jiraAPI call to add comments to the provided jiraInc
}

function handleJira(req, res) {
    var jiraInc = jiraCreate(req, res);
    jiraComment(req, res, jiraInc);
}

handleJira(req, res);
```

Of course, with the above, if req.body.inc is blank, jiraComment will just execute and state that the incident does not exist. How would I re-write it using callbacks to achieve my goal? Is it possible?

I've read so much on Callbacks and just can't seem to get it. No matter how I write my code, the jiraComment seems to always run first. I really appreciate any help provided!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "jiraAPI call to create ticket" is asynchronous... i.e. when you make a call the code is something along the lines of

```
http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  var body = "";
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
      // {1} Here you can continue with next step
  });
}).end();
```

You should place the code for next step in `{1}`. Placing it as you've done immediately after making the request will not work.